# Bootstrap 3 - When modal hides it hides content

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

When my modal form, which succesfully returns Ajax content, closes. The content dissappears.

```
<h4>Ajax Results</h4>
<div id="ajaxResults">
</div>
```

The underlying javascript is:

```
 $('#modalTBMSubmit').on('click', function (e){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"./services/addTypeBrandModel.php",
        data:$('#addTypeBrandModel').serialize(),
        success: function(msg){
            $('#ajaxResults').append('<strong>Success!</strong>');
        },
        error:function(){
            $('#ajaxResults').append('<strong>Failure!</strong>');
        }       
    });
```

My modal form is something this:

```
<div id="modalBrandModel" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
```

and I have not applied additional classes  to modal dialog. Any idea why "Success!" dissappears when I close the modal dialog?

Comment: Is `<div id="ajaxResults"></div>` inside the modal?

Comment: No, this its on a different area, right column, while modal resides in center column...

Comment: Could you post a more complete example of the HTML? It's hard to tell what is happening without the full context.

Comment: Can't post code to comment :(  But there is nothing more but 3 input text boxes and a button inside modal.

Comment: It would be most helpful to have the full page, as it stands now, you haven't included enough to reproduce it. You can edit your post and possibly include a JSFiddle if you are able to get it to reproduce

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion AnotherDev, I'm kinda new here...

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the page was doing a full reload because I had forgot to include in my javascript:

```
$('#modalTBMSubmit').on('click', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
```

Thank you.